# What is the VSTS character path limit

Tags: path, azure-devops, limit

What is the path limit on VSTS? I know the old versions of TFS had a 256 character limit but not sure about VSTS and can't find the info here. Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions)  <-- it mentions the tfs 256 limit but doesnt talk about VSTS path limit, only account names, work items etc..

thank you!

Comment: What do you mean the "path limit"? Both for VSTS and TFS, the 256 characters restrictions including: **account name**, **group name**, **process and process templates**, **Kanban boards** and **build quality**. So which one do you refer?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Version control path length. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions#team-foundation-version-control talks about TFS version control path length but not VSTS.

Comment: Yes, it's also restrict for VSTS. And the document Team Foundation version control means TFVC VCS, which is available for TFS and VSTS. You can find the details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version control path length restrictions are both for VSTS and TFS.

In the article [Naming restrictions and conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions) (except the part [Team Foundation Build (on-premises TFS only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions#team-foundation-build-on-premises-tfs-only)), all the restrictions are available for TFS and VSTS.

As it list the products and versions which are suitable for :

[image]

There are two Version Control System integrated in VSTS and TFS: [**Git** and **TFVC** (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc).

And for the part [Team Foundation version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions#team-foundation-version-control), it shows the restrictions for **TFVC** VCS (both available for TFS and VSTS).

So if you are using **TFVC** to manage your source code, you can find the restrictions listed in the article.

If you are using **Git** to version control your source code, the restriction as below:

- File and folder name length restriction: 255 characters.
- File and folder name  can not contain any of the following characters `"` `/` `:` `<` `>` `\` `*` `?` `|`
- Tag name length restriction: 380 characters
- File and folder name  can not contain any of the following characters `~` `^` `[` `*` `\` `:` `?`

Answer (score -1):

Windows imposes the 256 character limit, so if you are running against windows-based agents, you will definitely still run into that.  Linux agents will have a larger path size, though the file name is limited to 255.

Comment: Windows nowdays support disabling that restriction.